# JTable resize table header does autoscroll

Tags: java, swing

This is my issue. I have the code below. What it does is when I drag a column over the edge of the panel, my panel scrolls by itself.

However, the problem is, with this feature, every time I resize the column width, the panel also scrolls to the top.

For example, I have 1000 rows and I highlight the 999th row at the bottom. When I resize the column width, the panel scrolls to the top. How do I make the panel to stay at wherever I was?

I want my table to autoscroll horizontally, but not vertically.

```
table.getTableHeader().addMouseMotionListener(new MouseMotionAdapter() {
    public void mouseDragged(MouseEvent e)
    {
        Rectangle r = new Rectangle(e.getX(), e.getY(), 1, 1);
        ((JTableHeader)e.getSource()).scrollRectToVisible(r);
        table.scrollRectToVisible(r);
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are resetting `JTable`'s scroll bar position by this statement:

`table.scrollRectToVisible(r);`

Here x position of rectangle is correct, as it is same for `JTableHeader` and `JTable`. But y position should be different for both. But you are using y position from `JTableHeader` for `JTable` also.

To make it work correctly, get y position of `JViewPort` of `JScrollPane` used by `JTable`.
Use this y position for the rectangle used in above statement. This should correct the issue.